# How can I figure out the value of the clicked cell in a table which was generated in ASP?

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm generating a large table on a webapp using ASP.  I connect to an oracle database using ADODB.Recordset and fill a table with each row of data.  Whenever you click on the ID number (the first column of each row), there are 15 boxes at the bottom that will fill up with more data from the database.  [image: Heere is a screenshot]  I apologize for censoring the data, but you can see what I'm giong for.  The table fills up with data, and then there's another table at the bottom that, when an ID number is clicked, should fill up with more info for that Id.

The problem I'm having is that, as the Recordset is stepped through to fill up the table, it gets to the end and keeps pointing at the last record in the database.  I need to find a way to make it point at the record I clicked on so that it can get all of the data about that record.  Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Assuming you want to do this client side, I'd save off the ID plus extra 15 values into a JavaScript array as you're building the table. Then when you process the click, just locate the ID in the array and you'll have the other values at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 2 ways I know of that will do what you want.

1. Using JavaScript as @Ed suggested. This will give you results in
   your bottom table without a page refresh.
2. Using VBScript, generate a URL with a querystring with the ID you
   want. Use the ID to populate your bottom table. This will require a
   page refresh.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was originally generating a URL with a querystring (I should have posted some of my code), but that still wasn't working.  What i ended up doing was writing a subroutine to generate the bottom table and then calling it whenever a boolean was set true during the initial table generation.  It works great now.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I accepted your answer because it's the only answer and it's what I ended up doing

Comment: Actually, I like subroutines, and/or includes, for stuff like this. It makes the code a lot easier to read & debug. Glad you got it working.